# FileChannel not writing special characters properly

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

I'm trying to write some text into a file using a FileChannel. So far everything works fine except for the fact that umlauts are not written correctly.

```
Path fileChannel = Paths.get("c:/channel.txt");
try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(
        fileChannel,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
        StandardOpenOption.READ,
        StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {

    String response = "Würzburg";
    channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

}
```

In this example, I want to write `Würzburg` into the file, but when I open it, it contains the following: `WÃ¼rzburg`. The file itself is utf-8.

Any suggestions, what could be done?

edit:

Finally, I would like to read out the file again, for example like this:

```
try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(fileChannel, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) channel.size()];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    channel.read(bb);
    String request = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(request);

}
```

However, a comparison of the strings response and request shows that they are not identical.

Running on a Windows machine, Java 17 (IntelliJ configured with adoptium open jdk)

Comment: "but when I open it" - how *exactly* are you opening it? It's entirely possible that there's nothing wrong with the file, and you merely need to configure whatever's viewing it to say that it's UTF-8.

Comment: (It's also possible that you haven't configured the compiler appropriately for the string literal - if you change it to `String response = "W\u00FCrzburg";` then that would remove that possibilty.)

Comment: When you read the bytes encoding "Würzburg" in UTF-8 with iso-8859-1 (or windows-1252), you get the string "WÃ¼rzburg",  so the problem is likely how you're reading the resulting file.

Comment: @JonSkeet: no matter which editor is used to open the file (viewing in utf-8), or whether the content is read back in with a FileChannel, the result is always the same.

Comment: @Slevin: I suggest you look at the bytes stored in the file in a binary file editor. That will remove a lot of the opportunities for misdiagnosis.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `String response = "W\u00FCrzburg";`gets the job done correctly, but I want to generate the response adaptively. To get that done properly I thought `response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` would be the way.

Comment: I ran your code and open the resulting file with Notepad++ and everything looks fine. The string is fine and Notepad++ shows the file encoding as utf8. Same result with Notepad.

Comment: If changing the form of the string literal works, then the problem is with how the compiler is reading your source code - in other words, the value of `response` wasn't what you expected it to be. (Try logging `response.length()` and you'll see what I mean.) Unfortunately we don't know anything about how you're compiling or whether you're using an IDE etc, so it's hard to suggest anything else.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help. I have now set up a completely new project without Maven and here the whole thing seems to work. No idea why under Maven (built with IntelliJ and jdk 17) it causes this problem (although project.build.sourceEncoding is set to UTF-8).